# Using azure text-analytics on android studio

Tags: android, azure, text-analytics-api

I want to use Azure Text Analytics(extractKeyPhrases) on Android, but it make some error on my project. I'm wondering why I am getting this error.
The error occurs in 'client.extractKeyPhrases(text)'. I think the important part of the error is 'at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)'.
Help me plz !!! :(

my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextAnalyticsClient client = authenticateClient(KEY, ENDPOINT);

    extractKeyPhrasesExample(client);

}

static TextAnalyticsClient authenticateClient(String key, String endpoint) {
    return new TextAnalyticsClientBuilder()
            .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(key))
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .buildClient();
}

static void extractKeyPhrasesExample(TextAnalyticsClient client)
{
    // The text that need be analyzed.
    String text = "My cat might need to see a veterinarian.";

    System.out.printf("Recognized phrases: %n");

    for (String keyPhrase : client.extractKeyPhrases(text)) {
       Log.d("TextAnalytics",keyPhrase);
    }
}
```

build.grdle(project)

```
mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-ai-textanalytics/5.0.0'

    }
    maven {
        url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/1.0-2'

    }
```

build.grdle(app)

```
implementation 'com.azure:azure-ai-textanalytics:5.0.0'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
```

my error

```
2020-09-26 18:30:30.301 27287-27287/com.example.newtextanalytics E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1678)
    at com.azure.ai.textanalytics.TextAnalyticsClient.extractKeyPhrases(TextAnalyticsClient.java:457)
    at com.azure.ai.textanalytics.TextAnalyticsClient.extractKeyPhrases(TextAnalyticsClient.java:432)
    at com.example.newtextanalytics.MainActivity.extractKeyPhrasesExample(MainActivity.java:41)
    at com.example.newtextanalytics.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Answer (score 0):

Text Analytics Java SDK is using reactor core but Reactor 3 does not officially support or target Android.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#prerequisites

Currently, Text Analytics SDK is only for Java but not Android. We could try debug and see how this is not working, but we never proved that all our SDKs works in Android.

If you have other questions, you are welcome to create issues in Azure SDK for Java repo.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/textanalytics/azure-ai-textanalytics